# "Have said" vs "said": why is the present perfect tense used here?

Tags: grammar

> With only about a third of the Maui wildfire burn area searched, the
> death toll from what’s already the deadliest US wildfire in more than
> a century still could rise significantly, Hawaii authorities **have
> said**.

Why use "have said" instead of just "said"? Is "said" also OK here?